# How to get specific line and value in line seperate with coma from text file

Tags: vb.net, filereader, streamreader, programmatically-created

I want get value 1 in all line for get path string, and programmatically add cover to flowlayoutpanel.

in Resource/Game List.ini (from drag n drop)

> Apex Legends,Resource/Cover/Apex Legends.jpg,Resource/Game Info/Apex Legends.txt
>   Fortnite,Resource/Cover/Fortnite.jpg,Resource/Game Info/Fortnite.txt
>   PUBG,Resource/Cover/PUBG.jpg,Resource/Game Info/PUBG.txt

here my code :

```
Private Sub LabelSetting_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles LabelSetting.Click
        FlpAddItem.Controls.Clear()

        'I am confused in this part to get value 1 in all line for get path string
        'Directory.GetFiles(Path) will be replace with streamreader from lines(i) value 1

        Dim Path = '???
        Dim ImageX As Image = Nothing
        Dim x As Int32 = Directory.GetFiles(Path).Count - 1
        Dim Img(x) As PictureBox
        Dim ImgText(x) As Label
        Dim ImgPanel As Panel

        For i = 0 To Directory.GetFiles(Path).Count - 1
            ImgPanel = New Panel
            With ImgPanel
                .Width = 96
                .Height = 136
                .BackColor = Color.Transparent
            End With

            FlpAddItem.Controls.Add(ImgPanel) 'Add panel to the flowlayoutpanel

            ImgText(i) = New Label
            With ImgText(i)
                .Name = Directory.GetFiles(Path)(i).Replace(Path, "").Replace(".jpg", "").Replace(".png", "")
                .FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Popup
                .Width = 116
                .Height = 40
                .Padding = New Padding(0, 3, 0, 0)
                .TextAlign = ContentAlignment.TopCenter
                .Dock = DockStyle.Bottom
                .BackColor = Color.Transparent
                .ForeColor = Color.Black
            End With

            Img(i) = New PictureBox
            With Img(i)
                .Width = 96
                .Height = 96
                .Padding = New Padding(20, 20, 20, 20)
                .BackColor = Color.Transparent
                .BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
                .SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
            End With
            ImgPanel.Controls.Add(Img(i)) 'Add the picturebox to the panel

            ImageX = Image.FromFile(Directory.GetFiles(Path)(i), True)
            Img(i).Image = Image.FromFile(Directory.GetFiles(Path)(i))
            ImgText(i).Text = Directory.GetFiles(Path)(i)
            ImgPanel.Controls.Add(ImgText(i))
        Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest creating a class for the game name and path information

```
Public Class GamePath
    Public Property GameName As String
    Property Path As String

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return GameName
    End Function
End Class
```

I have overridden `ToString`, so that the game name will automatically be displayed in a ListBox.

When loading the form, I read this information from the INI-file and set it as data source of a listbox, where you will be able to select a game.

```
Private Sub Form_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim games =
        From line In File.ReadLines(IniFilePath)
        Let parts = line.Split(","c)
        Select New GamePath With {.GameName = parts(0), .Path = parts(1)}
    GameListBox.DataSource = games.ToList()
    GameListBox.SelectedIndex = 0 'Select first game
End Sub
```

Note that it is easier to use `File.ReadLines` than a StreamReader. You will have to add `Imports System.IO` to the top of the code. Then we use the LINQ syntax to split each line at the comma and to create the game path information.

The user selects a game in the ListBox and then clicks a button. You can get the file path information from the ListBox like this:

```
Dim gamePath As GamePath = DirectCast(GameListBox.SelectedItem, GamePath)
```

Then read the files only once and assign the result to a variable

```
Dim files As String() = Directory.GetFiles(gamePath.Path)
```

Get the file count

```
Dim fileCount As Integer = files.Count
```

The whole Click method:

```
Private Sub StartGameButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles StartGameButton.Click
    FlpAddItem.Controls.Clear()

    Dim gamePath As GamePath = DirectCast(GameListBox.SelectedItem, GamePath)
    Dim files As String() = Directory.GetFiles(gamePath.Path)
    Dim fileCount As Integer = files.Count

    Dim ImageX As Image = Nothing
    Dim Img(fileCount) As PictureBox
    Dim ImgText(fileCount) As Label
    Dim ImgPanel As Panel

    For i = 0 To fileCount - 1
        Dim filePath = files(i)
        ImgPanel = New Panel
        With ImgPanel
            .Width = 96
            .Height = 136
            .BackColor = Color.Transparent
        End With

        FlpAddItem.Controls.Add(ImgPanel) 'Add panel to the flowlayoutpanel

        ImgText(i) = New Label
        With ImgText(i)
            .Name = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath)
            .FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Popup
            .Width = 116
            .Height = 40
            .Padding = New Padding(0, 3, 0, 0)
            .TextAlign = ContentAlignment.TopCenter
            .Dock = DockStyle.Bottom
            .BackColor = Color.Transparent
            .ForeColor = Color.Black
        End With

        Img(i) = New PictureBox
        With Img(i)
            .Width = 96
            .Height = 96
            .Padding = New Padding(20, 20, 20, 20)
            .BackColor = Color.Transparent
            .BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
            .SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
        End With
        ImgPanel.Controls.Add(Img(i)) 'Add the picturebox to the panel

        ImageX = Image.FromFile(filePath, True)
        Img(i).Image = Image.FromFile(filePath)
        ImgText(i).Text = filePath
        ImgPanel.Controls.Add(ImgText(i))
    Next
End Sub
```

Some details:

In the For-loop you can get the path of an image file with

```
Dim filePath = files(i)
```

You can get the name of the image with

```
.Name = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath)
```

This automatically removes the directory name and the extension.

Later on, you don't call `Directory.GetFiles` again:

```
ImageX = Image.FromFile(filePath, True)
Img(i).Image = Image.FromFile(filePath)
ImgText(i).Text = filePath
```

---

If you only want to read the file paths into a list, you could write

```
Dim games =
    (From line In File.ReadLines(IniFilePath)
     Select line.Split(","c)(1)).ToList()
```

Comment: Thank you sir, the code worked well.
I in vb net only ventured, I learned self-taught without any basic programming and try to learn it.

and thank you once again

Comment: Sir, i have a problem,, "The directory name is invalid" maybe this part `Dim files As String() = Directory.GetFiles(gamePath.Path)` while in the .ini file path with name extensions,, What should I do

Comment: [Tutorial: Learn to debug Visual Basic code using Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/visual-basic/tutorial-debugger?view=vs-2019). Debug and look what is inside `gamePath.Path`. See also: [First look at the Visual Studio Debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2019)

Comment: If you google for [debug visual basic](https://www.google.com/search?q=debug+visual+basic) you will find also video tutorials and much more on this subject.